# Tekton running pipeline via passing parameter

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have a Tekton `Pipeline` and `PipelineRun` definitions. But, I couldn't achieve to run `Pipeline` via passing parameter.

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  generateName: build-deploy-
  labels:
    tekton.dev/pipeline: build-deploy
spec:
  serviceAccountName: tekton-build-bot
  pipelineRef:
    name: build-deploy
  params:
    - name: registry-address
      value: $(REG_ADDRESS)
    - name: repo-address
      #value: $(REPO_ADDRESS)
      value: $(REPO_ADDRESS)
    - name: repo-name
      value: $(REPO_NAME)
    - name: version
      value: $(VERSION)
  workspaces:
    - name: source
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-pvc
```

How can I pass while parameters while trying to run that runner with the following command `kubectl create -f pipelinerun.yaml`?

Example:

`value: $(REG_ADDRESS)` -> I wanted to pass registry address as right before the running pipeline instead of giving hard-coded constant.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass those parameters when using `kubectl create`.

There are two alternatives:

### Use tkn cli

You can use [tkn](https://github.com/tektoncd/cli), a purpose made CLI for Tekton. Then you can start a run of a Pipeline with, e.g.:

```
tkn pipeline start build-deploy \
    --param registry-address=yay \
    --param repo-name=nay \
    --workspace name=source,claimName=my-pvc
```

### Initiate pipeline with Trigger

You can setup a [Trigger](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers) that initiates runs of your Pipeline on certain events, e.g. when you push to Git.

Then your `PipelineRun` template with parameter mapping is done using a [TriggerTemplate](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/main/docs/triggertemplates.md)

Comment: thanks Jonas, I was aware of cli commands but I couldn't think to use it. Currenty, I develop my pipeline locally. So, configuring triggerTemplate can be hard. What is the best approach to define pipeline trigger? For now, I should go with manual trigger with the cli.

Comment: The trigger is configured against a git repo. For local development. installing the `tkn` cli is the easiest approach.

Answer (score -1):

another example would be as bellow:

```
 tkn pipeline start pipeline-name --showlog \
 -w name=namespace-name,claimName=youor-pvc \
 -w name=git-credentials,secret=gh-token \
 -p repo-url=https://github.com/your-url \
 -p revision=REV-507
```